# What is the first part of a joke called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, humor

How does one refer to the first part of a joke?

The follow up is often referred to as a punchline but I'm unsure how to refer to the first part. Is it a 'joke' or does a 'joke' include the punchline?

Comment: I usually use the term "run-up".

Comment: Related: in a comedy team, the run-up or set-up delivered by a straight-man is called a straightline (which, incidentally, is the shortest distance between two puns).

Comment: @ChrisCudmore bravo.

Comment: I think "rising action" would be suitable. It's a literary reference and ties into "risible". Of course, that's me projecting where there is established terminology.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The first part of the joke is the **[setup](http://www.writersdock.com/2011/10/02/the-stand-up-comedy-formula/)**, a general question or observation which offers an opportunity to give the punchline in response.

The joke is the setup and punchline combined, as either on its own is not inherently funny, in contrast to a *one-liner*. To the setup and punchline may also be added *tags*, additional punchlines using the same setup, and *toppers*, additional punchlines which use the entire earlier joke as a setup.

Comment: Here's a joke about UDP...

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald A handshake for you, good sir

Comment: The best part about UDP jokes is that nobody cares if you get them.

Comment: A punchline by itself might be inherently funny if the joke is based on the lack of context (i.e. an [orphaned punchline](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrphanedPunchline))

Comment: I love how this proves that EVERYONE gets sidetracked (from real work at overflow or superuser) by the 'somewhat related but definitely from a different stack exchange site' side panel.

Don't get me wrong, though; I love how the next generation of coders will have a substantial appreciation of english and UX!!!

Comment: There are so many good comments on this answer I keep having to waiting yet-another-5-seconds in order to upvote them all.

Comment: @lol: Not to mention scifi/fantasy trivia..

Comment: @Gareth: I should put in a feature request to get all links to TVtropes banned during work hours.

Answer (score 27):

Set-up is what professional comics/writers call it. Here in the UK some also call it a `feedline` as opposed to `punchline`.

Comment: I believe 'feedline' is only used of a setup delivered by a different person than the punchline.

Comment: The setup might be a lot longer than the feedline. The feedline is the line before the punch line (if that makes sense). It is the line off which the punchline can be made.